# WebService en C# y .Net metodo POST

Tags: c#, webservice

Entiendo que necesito credenciales y un token, ya los tengo, también la configuración del `HttpWebRequest (Get)`

Al momento de hacer el `POST` entiendo que debo hacer un `GET` primero, el `web service` al que recurro recibe datos en `json`, el `json` ya lo tengo también.

El problema es que me manda un error en esta linea

```
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Mandando el siguiente error

> **System.Net.WebException: 'Error en el servidor remoto: (400) Solicitud incorrecta.'**

A que se debe esto... llevo mucho intentando

Este es mi codigo completo

```
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://mi pagina");

            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Token taltoken");
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";


            Vehiculo vehiculo = new Vehiculo
            {
                id= "14",
                created_at= "13-03-2019 17:17:03",
                vin = txt_VIN.Text,
                rfv= "0",
                model_year= 2012,
                type_vehicle= "1",
                type_service= "TAXI",
                class_vehicle= "1",
                mark = "SEAT",
                submark = "IBIZA_2.0L",
                num_motor = "9876",
                cilinders = 4,
                displacement = 1600,
                gas = "GASOLINA",
                status = "ACTIVE",
                invoce_value = 12000,
                vehicular_key = 11232,
                doors = 4
            };

            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            string outputJSON = ser.Serialize(vehiculo);


            //En esta linea se queda
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                string result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(result);
            }
```

Comment: El error 400 se da cuando se envia una solicitud incorrecta, algo estas configurando mal. Por ejemplo si estas haciendo un post, pero solo soporta get o viceversa, algun parametro incorrecto etc. Lo mejor es coloques todo el codigo relacionado a la peticion. Claro que los datos sencibles como credenciales o token los reemplazas por xxxx.

Comment: Agrega mas informacion como haces el post y cuales parametros se esperan del lado del servidor?

Comment: Ya lo he puesto, gracias por su atención

Comment: estas realizando dos invocaciones a la misma url, solo que la segunda la pones dentro del using, pero es lo mismo. No veo donde pasas el json que serializas de la clase

Comment: si esta dos veces porque la saque para ver mas claro el error, ya que no sabia si entraba al using, para el json que en este caso seria outputJSON, en los ejemplos que he visto, no se donde se manda en la linea :    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a mi esto me funciona con C# y una API realizada con PHP, si lo puedes adaptar a tu necesidad, creo que no seria mucha la diferencia.

Esto lo utilizo para hacer login con mi base de datos en MySQL.

Para serializar puedes utilizar

```
  using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

y creas clases para recibir la respuesta de tu request.

```
//clases
public class datosL
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
    public class RootObjectlist
    {
        public string resultado { get; set; }
        public datosL datos { get; set; }
        public string mensaje { get; set; }
    }
```

Esto lo puedes poner en algun evento de tu boton

```
            string juser = user;
            string jpass = pass;
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www");
            req.KeepAlive = true;
            req.Method = "POST";
            string Data = "id=" + juser + "&pass=" + jpass;//aqui poner tu objeto serializado con las variables que se recibiran en el WS
            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data);
            // req.Headers = "application/json";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
            Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            var msjdes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectlist>(responseText);

            string mjsserver = msjdes.resultado;
            string msjservernot = msjdes.mensaje;
            if (mjsserver == "OK")
            {
                string usuario = msjdes.datos.Username;
                string password = msjdes.datos.Password;

                if (textBox1.Text == usuario && textBox2.Text == password)
                {
                    NameUserGlobal = usuario;

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("El Usuario o Password estan incorrectos");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(msjservernot,"Información incorrecta");

            }
```

No estoy seguro si es la mejor manera de hacerlo, pero a mi me funciona, prueba y me comentas.